# i can't add data to the database

Tags: mysql

Server Error in '/' Application.

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 29,Token in error = - ]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 29,Token in error = - ]

error message :

Line 13:          var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO register (name,e-mail,college)" + "VALUES (@0,@1,@2)";
Line 14:          var db = Database.Open("Empty Site2");
Line 15:          db.Execute(SQLINSERT,formName,formEmail,formCollege,formMobileNumber,formAddress);
Line 16:     }
Line 17:

this is my source code :

```
var formName = "";
var formEmail =  "";
var formCollege = ""; 
var formMobileNumber = "";
var formAddress = "";
if(IsPost) {
     formName = Request["name"];
     formEmail =  Request["email"];
     formCollege = Request["collegename"];
     formMobileNumber = Request["mobilenumber"];
     formAddress = Request["address"];
     var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO register (name,e-mail,college)" + "VALUES (@0,@1,@2)";
     var db = Database.Open("Empty Site2");
     db.Execute(SQLINSERT,formName,formEmail,formCollege,formMobileNumber,formAddress);
```

Comment: This is not PHP code. There's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a whitespace between the column list and the `values` keyword:

```
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO register (name,e-mail,college)" + " VALUES (@0,@1,@2)";
```

Comment: There is no required whitespace there as far as I'm aware.